# How to call a another python program from a python program and arguments are passed while calling

Tags: python, angularjs, cmd, cron-task

For eg,

Script1.py  contains program to add two numbers.i want to call this file from script2.py and passing values.how its possible?
Note :file script1.py is not placed in same folder.

Script1:

num1 = a;
num2 = b;

## //Add two numbers

sum = float(num1) + float(num2)

## //Display the sum

print('The sum of {0} and {1} is {2}'.format(num1, num2, sum))

Script2:

## //There is function to call script 1

def hello():

```
 subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'python','/MyRepository/services/uploaded/programmingAssignments/sum.py', '2', '2'])
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try or at least searched for documentation?

Answer (score 0):

> script1.py

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', '/home/pi/script2.py', '2', '2'])
```

> script2.py

```
sum = sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2]
```

Comment: There is no `sudo` implied in the question.

Comment: It is now. Before you removed the `sudo`, your answer implied that all python scripts would have to run `sudo`. Not a good thing to teach people...

Comment: How to consume values from script2.py  to a and b??

Comment: a=sys.argv[1]
b=sys.argv[2]

Comment: doc='"/home/uploaded/programmingAssignments/sum.py"'
        p=subprocess.Popen('python' + doc, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output=p.communicate()
        print output                                                                                   When running this python code,get OSError -
[Errno 2] No such file or directory   .How to solve this problem    ?

Comment: Write for a new question. This is closed.